# vector.erase - it deletes my last element always

Tags: c++, vector, erase

First time here, an amateur programmer, I have quite a bit of issue. I want to make a virtual model shop. I can add new items, check the inventory, all in a vector but when I want to delete a specific item (by `producer`&`name`&`scale`) it always deletes the last element.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class model
{
private:
    int price;
    string scale, name, producer;
public:

    vector<model> vectorr;
    model();
    virtual ~model();
    int getprice();
    string getscale();
    string getname();
    string getproducer();

    void setprice(int);
    void setscale(string);
    void setname(string);
    void setproducer(string);
    friend ostream &operator>>(ostream &stream, model &mt);
    model &operator=(model &mt);
};
```

That's the header.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header1.h"
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<machete> vectorr;
    machete c;
    machete t;

    cout << "Welcome to the shop , what do you want to do?" << endl;
    cout << "Chose your destiny : 1. Add  2.Get 3.Remove  4.Sort  0.Quit"   << endl;

    int menu, temp2;
    string temp;

    cin >> menu;

    while (menu != 0) {
        switch (menu) {
            case 0 : cout << "Bye bye";
                _getch();
                exit(1);
                break;
            case 1 : cout << "Enter a producer" << endl;
                cin >> temp;
                c.setproducer(temp);
                cout << "Enter a name" << endl;
                cin >> temp;
                c.setname(temp);
                cout << "Enter a scale" << endl;
                cin >> temp;
                c.setscale(temp);
                cout << "Enter a price" << endl;
                cin >> temp2;
                c.setprice(temp2);
                vectorr.push_back(c);
                cout << "You have succesfully added a model !" << endl;
                break;

            case 2 : cout << "Producer  |  Name  |  Scale  | Price" << endl;
                for (std::vector<model>::iterator it = vectorr.begin(); it != vectorr.end(); ++it) {
                    cout >> *it;
                }
                cout << endl;
                break;

            case 3 : cout << "What do you want to remove?" << endl;
                cout << "Enter the producer" << endl;
                string producer;
                cin >> producer;
                cout << "Enter the name" << endl;
                string name;
                cin >> name;
                cout << "Enter the scale" << endl;
                string scale;
                cin >> scale;
                for (unsigned i = 0; i < vectorr.size(); ++i) {
                    t.setname(vectorr[i].getnume());
                    t.setproducer(vectorr[i].getproducator());
                    t.setscale(vectorr[i].getscara());
                    if (t.getname() == name && t.getproducer() == producer && t.getscle() == scale) {
                        vectorr.erase(vectorr.begin() + i);
                        cout << "You have succesfully erased the " << name << " model" << endl;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        cout << "Chose your destiny : 1. Add  2.Get  3.Remove  4.Sort  0.Quit" << endl;

        cin >> menu;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

That's the main. `case 3` is the problem deleting `thingamajack`. It always deletes the last element in my vector. The if(name=name and so on) works properly, tested it three times to be sure that wasn't the problem. It appears whatever I write `vectorr.erase` just won't work the way I want it to.

Sorry for the messy code, I might have done something wrong before the `case 3`, ignore `case 4` the sort, not implemented yet, any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Could you show the input that you use to check this behaviour?

Comment: Not related to the erase issue, but in the second case didn't you want to print out data with `cout << *it;` instead of `cout>>*it;` ?

Comment: **1.** How do you check what it erases and what's left? **2.** If we are to spend time helping you, could you invest some yourself and provide compiling and properly indented code?

Comment: Another unrelated item: if the user chooses to exit the program, don't do `exit(1);` as a return code other than 0 indicates an error condition.

Comment: Likely a faulty copy operator, I guess

Comment: I used as input
 1;
 Producer : a;
 Name : a;
 Scale : 1/72;
 Price : 1
;1;
Producer : aaa;
Name : aaa;
Scale : 1/72;
Price : 2;
1;
Producer : aa;
Name : aa;
Scale : 1/72;
Price : 4;
Then I introduce 2 so you can see the inventory which looks like :

          a-a-1/72-1
          aaa-aaa-1/72-2
          aa-aa-1/72-4
I press 3 and introduce
Producer: a;
Name: a;
Scale 1/72;

And when I press 2 again I get:

         a-a-1/72-1
         aaa-aaa-1/72-2

See my point? It always deletes the last one.

Comment: Also, I made the '>>*it' to print out data the way I wanted because 'cout<<*it' gave me the no operator << matches the operands .

Answer (score 0):

In case 2, you've written

```
std::vector<model>::iterator it = vectorr.begin()
```

whereas you defined

```
vector<machete> vectorr;
```

I think you've confused between machete and model.

Comment: it's the same, i translated it to make sense to you... machete=model in my language, missed it apparently

Comment: You should mention that! Otherwise the code seems good to run. You can use _gdb_ to track down what's happening inside.